# Grunt concat js angularjs not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, angular-ui, concatenation

```
tets: {

            src: [
                'app/modules/test/js/test-app.js',
                'app/modules/test/js/services/test-service.js',
                'app/modules/test/js/controllers/test-enter-qty.js',
                'app/modules/test/js/controllers/test-print-upc.js',
                'app/modules/test/js/directives/test-print-upc.js'
            ],
            dest: 'app/js/test.js'
        }
```

I am trying to concat, when i load concated JS, the module itself not working at all..

Not able to get anything in console.log

Comment: Have you tried to add `--verbose` flag when you call grunt?

Answer (score 0):

Try - https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate

This generator has some sample codes on that - https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack/blob/master/app/templates/Gruntfile.js